# Which regular expression matches lines with multiple text strings in any order?

Tags: regex

- Line.1: It was a rainy day today.
- Line 2: Yesterday was a windy day.
- Line 3: Rain fell from the sky today.

The strings "day" and "rain" should be in that line, so that should find Lines 1 and 3.

#### Which regular expression is able to find the lines with any given multiple text strings?

Preferably not limited to two strings.

Comment: Show us expected result.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

With a Unix like shell :

```
grep 'day' file | grep 'rain'
```